# Delete a directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I want to delete all files and folders in the directory, without deleting the root directory.

For eg: My tree structure is C:\app\temp.

The temp folder has a dist_timestamp folder and the dist folder has few files and folders. I would like to delete starting from dist folder, however if I am going to delete a dist_timestamp folder tomorrow, I cannot regenerate the timestamp the folder was created on. So technically, I would like to remove all folders under temp, without deleting temp.

I used rmdir /q C:\app\temp, and this seems to remove the temp folder also. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

`REM Opening the folder.
CD C:\app\
REM Deleting temp folder with all subdirectories and files.
RMDIR /S /Q temp
REM Creating new temp folder.
MKDIR temp`

/S - Force deleting of read-only files.
/Q - Quite mode, do not ask if it ok to remove a directory tree with /S

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
pushd "C:\app\temp" && (rd /s /q . 2>nul&popd)
```